# You might have heard this one before, on the ride home. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

You can force it, but it will not come.
You can taste it, but it will not fall.
You can crush it, but it's always here.
You can crush it, but it's always near.
You can force it, but it will stay stung.
You can crush it as dry as a bone.
You can walk it home straight from school.
You can kiss it.
You can break all the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: You might have heard this one before, on the ride home. Who am I?
-- SPOILER ALERT --

> Everyone! Everyone is broken. 
>
>  The answer is actually contained in the lyrics to Radiohead's "Planet Telex", which is where the riddle originates. Thanks for playing!

Answer (score 2):

You've taken lyrics from a song (without attribution, which is plagiarism - for content that you did not create yourself, you need to **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**) and posted them as a riddle.

It's possible you created your own riddle which these lyrics conveniently convey nicely, so you have your own intended answer; I suspect if that's the case then your riddle is going to be ***too broad*** because there's nothing to distinguish your intended meaning from whatever meaning(s) the original song lyrics might have.  As this is somewhat unlikely anyway, I'm assuming this is not the case.

The other possibility is that you're asking about what the song lyrics mean.  So ...

> As has been said elsewhere, these lyrics are from ["Planet Telex" by Radiohead](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/radiohead/planettelex.html).  (Again, you really need to provide attribution!)  But while there is a lot of speculation and opinion about what these lyrics might mean, there's no definitive answer.  In fact:
>
>  `Lead singer Thom Yorke was drunk and improvising when he recorded the vocals. The band came to the studio after drinking a lot of wine, and Yorke lied on the floor and sang. He did only one take.`
>  $\hskip{20em}$<sup>[—Songfacts](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=1540)</sup>
>
>
>  ...which makes it, well, fairly improbable there's an intentional meaning to the lyrics.  That leaves it a matter of interpretation, and there's no particular shortage of ideas about [what these lyrics might mean](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/568/) — but I'm not sure how you would pick one as a "right" answer.

I'm guessing, therefore, that

> this riddle has no definite answer, and we're now well into ***primarily opinion-based*** territory.  Here's to hoping I'm wrong — and if I am, you may wish to clarify that in your question. (And while you're at it, don't forget to **add attribution** for the lyrics!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the entire riddle is

> lyrics from the song Radiohead - Planet Telex. https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/radiohead/planettelex.html

And

> No one really knows what the lyrics reference. In my opinion it refers to depression.

Comment: You have the riddle, but not the answer. You can't kiss depression nor can you walk it home from school.

Comment: @phish_bulb in a metaphorical sense, you can. it's basically how depression works.